# InsertCell() difference in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, insert, cell

I'm adding cells into a table in a for loop but result is different in ie and chrome. Cells are in opposite order.

Such as;

IE       `[[cell_1][cell_2][cell_3][cell_4]]`

Chrome   `[[cell_4][cell_3][cell_2][cell_1]]`

Why would such problem happen, and is there a way to add cells with some other methods (maybe jQuery)?

I use **ie 10.0.9** and **chrome 30.0.1**

---

**Update:**

You can try it with this code in both browsers;

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fillTable(){
            var aTBL = document.getElementById("table");

            aTR = aTBL.insertRow();

            for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                aTD = aTR.insertCell();
                aTD.innerHTML = "[cell_" + i + "]";
            }
        }
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table">
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        fillTable();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like browsers have different default values, where to insert the cell, if you're not passing an argument to `insertCell()`. Pass `-1` as an argument, then the cell is appended at the end of a row.

```
aTD = aTR.insertCell(-1);
```